# Does “it” change the meaning in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

> By which vehicle is it more safety to travel , a plane or a train ?
>
> Which vehicle is more safety to travel , a plane or a train ?

Does “it” change the meaning in the sentence below? Or Is there a little difference ? I really couldn’t understand .

Comment: Both your examples are syntactically invalid. We'd usually use ***safer*** rather than ***more safe*** anyway, but 1: *By which vehicle **is it** more safe to travel...?* and 2: *Which vehicle is more safe to travel **in**?* are valid. You could *optionally* include ***it*** in #2, and/or replace ***in*** with ***on*** or ***by***. The preposition can be moved to the *start* of the utterance; in which case ***it*** must be included; ***By** which vehicle is **it safer** to travel...?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neither of your sentences are correct.**

"safety" is a noun. What you need in both these sentences is the adjective "safe".

> It is safe to travel.
>
> It is more safe to travel.

Making that change makes the first sentence correct, except that I would put a colon instead of a comma. Colons are usually used to introduce a list.

> By which vehicle is it more safe to travel: a plane or a train?

The second sentence also needs a preposition. You do not "travel a plane" you "travel *in* a plane". (the preposition can vary between "in" or "on" depending on the transport). So your second sentence should be:

> Which vehicle is more safe to travel in: a plane or a train?